# Copy and paste as value to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

i have a code

```
Sub Copy_Past()

Dim wsOne As Worksheet
Dim wsTwo As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long

'Load workbooks
    Set wsOne = Workbooks("SomeFile1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsTwo = Workbooks("SomeFile2.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Find Last row
    lCopyLastRow = wsOne.Cells(wsOne.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row

'Copy and past
  wsOne.Range("A2:A" & lCopyLastRow).Copy 
    wsTwo.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

and problem is with .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues beacuse it only past value "pastespecial xlvalues" not value from wsOne workbook. I don't know why

Comment: for me your code works, i.e all values from column A on sheet1 in SomeFile1 are copied to Column A Sheet2 in SomeFile2

Comment: Kaseox, suggest you put `Option Explicit` at the top of your code; seeing how Ike's code works, maybe there are some other issues.